# Can I use the same save file for different copies of a Switch game?

Tags: nintendo-switch

A friend lent me his copy of Mario + Rabbids to play on my own Switch. I ended up enjoying it a lot and I want to buy my own copy, but I don't want to lose my progress.

If I buy a separate physical or digital copy of a game, will I still be able to play with my save file?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

### Yes

[From Nintendo directly](http://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/22289/p/897):

> **Where is game save data Stored?**
>
> - On Nintendo Switch, game save data is stored on the console’s System Memory.
>   This will not change whether downloadable software or software from a game
>   card is being played.
> - Game save data cannot be saved or copied to a microSD card.
>
> **Can save data be used between physical and digital games on Nintendo Switch?**
>
> - Save data is stored in the System Memory, and for the most part, it is associated to the individual user. So long as the same user is selected on the console, the save data will not be impacted whether the software is played from a game card or downloaded from the Nintendo eShop.

Answer (score 10):

Yes. Switch cartridges are read-only, your saves are stored on the system.

Answer (score -4):

I spoke with a representative from Nintendo, and no, the data will not be saved; you'd essentially be starting with an entirely new game.

Comment: This is contrary to the other official Nintendo source in the accepted answer, and it also goes against my own personal experience. Do you have any supporting evidence?