# lost splatoon 2 gamecard... if I buy a new gamecard, is my data saved on the switch? or will I have to restart?

Tags: nintendo-switch, splatoon-2

My gamecard has been missing for quite some time, and from the announcement of splatoon 3 ive wanted to play it more than ever, but I cannot find this card. i've gotten very far in the game though - if I buy a replacement gamecard, will i be able to pick up where I left off using game data from the switch or is this not possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I use the same save file for different copies of a game?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/321080/can-i-use-the-same-save-file-for-different-copies-of-a-game)

Answer (score 0):

According to Nintendo, whatever you do in-game, will be saved onto your Nintendo Switch's system memory, therefore allowing you to continue where you left off. Also, your data should still be there even if you buy the digital version of Splatoon, so you can still play where you left off on the cartridge version of the game.

You can find even more information about the system's data management on Nintendo's customer support website [here](https://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/22289/p/897).